# change a TextField name in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to change a `TextField` variable name but I can't find the option that allows me that.

I tried to change it from the source code but `Netbeans` doesn't allow me to do that, I also Googled about it but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rename a component in `NetBeans`:

- Select the component to rename
- Click on the window `Properties Window->Code`
- Change `Variable Name`

Answer (score 2):

To rename the component in netbeans :

```
   1. select the component
   2. right click on the component.
   3. Edit the variable name 
      And it's done :)
```