# Java- How to set a variable/id name to different JTextFields?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a frame and 2 panels in Java, the first panel have some buttons and the other panel will show the new TextFields. After those textfields are created. I want to get the text in each textfield but i dont know how to get each text if i dont have an specific variable name for each one.

```
public class GUIListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource()==boton2){
                System.out.println("boton 2");
                takeData();
            }else if(e.getSource()==boton3){
                System.out.println("boton 3");
                createTextFields(4);
            }
        }
    }

    public void createTextFields(int quantity){

        panel2.removeAll();
        for(int i =0;i<quantity;i++){
            texto = new JTextField("TF # "+i);
            panel2.add(texto);
        }
        panel2.validate();
        panel2.repaint();
    }

    public void takeData(){
        System.out.println(texto.getText());   
        //Only prints the text of the last textfield created
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a variable that you actually do want to use?

Comment: @markspace for example in this link it shows you how to change the variable name in a textfield https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089536/change-a-textfield-name-in-netbeans. In this case i want to create 4 textfields, after they were created i want to get the text of each textfield, but all of them were created by "texto" variable, i want each textfield have a different name, such as texto1, texto2 ,texto3,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save all the `JTextField`s in a collection or array and return them.

```
public JTextField[] createTextFields(int quantity) {
    panel2.removeAll();
    JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[quantity];
    for(int i =0;i<quantity;i++) {
        texto = new JTextField("TF # "+i);
        panel2.add(texto);
        textFields[i] = texto;
    }
    panel2.validate();
    panel2.repaint();
    return textFields;
}
```